# How To Configure Redux DevTools Within Chrome Inspector Window So That Elements Are Stacked vs. Side-by-Side?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

How do I configure my Redux DevTool within the Chrome Inspector window so that they are stacked like they are in the red square? Currently my view is the one in blue where they are side-by-side.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out by accident. The solution is very technical. You have to click and drag the left hand edge to the right. Dragging right will stack the view. Dragging left will expand the view.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Here you can see, they have provided 3 kinds of view,]

there you can find three ways to view your redux devtools.

Comment: Cool. Yeah I played with those buttons as well. While the view is what I'm looking for, it displays this in a new window (as shown in the red square in my OP). I was looking for that stacked view within the same inspector window. I was able to figure out the solution earlier today. You just need to the click and drag the left hand edge towards the right and it will eventually result in a stacked view.

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer ended up just being that I had to restart Chrome after initially installing the Redux Dev Tools extension. Before I restarted, it wasn't showing up in the inspector.

Answer (score -1):

As said above, just restart Chrome or Edge, whatever you are using, and will be added automatically.